# Segmentation Fault with Large Input

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I know `segmentation fault` means that the process has attempted to access certain memory that it's not allowed to.

I'm running some program written by others using C++. And when my input is large (around 1GB), there'll be a segmentation fault even though I requested 30GB memory; while when input size is quite small, it goes well.

So what shall I do? Is it because there's not enough memory? I'm really kind of a newbie without much knowledge of C++. I don't even know which part of the code controls memory allocation.

Thanks to BLender, line from the debugging is:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003fbd653174 in _IO_vfscanf_internal ()
   from /share/bin/intel/cc/10.1.015/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6`

Comment: well you should start by posting the relative code.

Comment: Could be hard coded constraints in the program.

Comment: yeah, i can show code...but code is just too complicated....i can show anyway

Comment: You should really mention what OS you're using and whether it's 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: The `const float inf=10000000000;` is completely wrong; floats have a value to represent infinity with. Later casting that to an int is even more wrong; you should use MAX_INT or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `malloc` several times, but never `free`, so it uses quite a lot of memory. And it never checks for an out-of-memory condition...

My suggestion is that you change all the calls to malloc to something like:

```
size_t total_memory = 0;
void *my_malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *res = malloc(sz);
    total_memory += sz;
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("Too much memory eaten: %zu\n", total_memory);
        abort();
    }
    return res;
}
#define malloc(x) my_malloc(x)
```

And see what happens.

Comment: thx...but how can I change? I search 'malloc' in the code, and find, say "clusterIdElNew = (clusterIdEl *) malloc(sizeof(clusterIdEl));"...then how can I change?

Comment: Well... I've added a macro that should make this automatic. Just add the previous code at the top of the file, after the `#include` lines.

Comment: I added it to the top after #include,....but still doesn't work...but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

> even I request 30GB memory

Do you *have* 30GB of memory? I *really* doubt it.

The answer depends on the function of the program. If the program reads and processes data without memory (i.e., the data that was read before doesn't influence the processing of the data being read), you can load the file in chunks.

But without details, I can't say much more.

---

Debug your program. When you compile it, enable debugging:

```
g++ -g -o program -Wall program.cpp
```

And use `gdb` to debug it:

```
gdb program
(gdb) run
```

And the line number and function that caused the segfault should show up.

Comment: yeah, i could. I'm on kind of hpcc system. I can request those 48GB-memory machine.

Comment: I didn't say you *don't*, I said that you *probably* don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they have a fixed-sized buffer in there, and your "large input"s are too large to fit inside it. C++ does not check these things by default (if they had used nice checked data structures from the STL perhaps, but clearly they didn't do that).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program in a debugger, but first make sure it is compiled with debugging information (-g). Run it with the data it segvaults on. It may be that your program tries to allocate large amount of memory with a call to malloc or new and assign it to a pointer, doesn't check if that was successful and then tries to access the memory (via the pointer) which was supposed to be allocated. You would see where it happens by examining stack trace after the segmentation violation in the debugger. That should give you a clue which part of the program should be modified so e.g. it doesn't read in the whole input file but only a chunk of it, in a loop.